# RadioButton CForm Yii

Tags: forms, yii

```
<?php echo $form->radioButton($model,'sex',array('value'=>'1')) . 'Male'; ?>
<?php echo $form->radioButton($model,'sex',array('value'=>'2')) . 'Female'; ?>
```

RadioButton "Female" on check writes to base correct value (2), but "Male" always writes 0

Update:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'sex'); ?>
    <?php $form->radioButtonList($model, 'sex', array('1'=>'Male', '2'=>'Female')); ?>
</div>
```

this code outputs label only.

Comment: check my answer, should work now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the echo.

```
<?php echo $form->radioButtonList($model, 'sex', array('1'=>'Male', '2'=>'Female')); ?>
```

No silly mistakes my friend :p

Answer (score 0):

You can try readiobutton list instead of creating radio button individually.

```
   echo $form->radioButtonList($model, 'sex', array('1'=>'Male', '2'=>'Female'));
```

Comment: In edited question, you didn't use echo ? Did you try?

Comment: @odminchek why -1 for my answer? As per your old question , i answered. But you have updated your question as per my answer. But some blind user downvoted my answer.